# How to include pages generated at build time?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I seek to make an "API Reference" page exposing `genindex.html` and `py-modindex.html`; problem is, I rather the entire page not be just clickable links to said pages, but to actually *include* their contents.  We can do this with a [README](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spatialaudio/nbsphinx/0.7.1/doc/index.rst) - however, `README.rst` exists in `source/`, whereas `genindex.html` is only in `build/`, so below don't work:

```
.. include:: modindex
.. include:: genindex
.. include:: modindex.rst
.. include:: genindex.rst
.. include:: ../build/genindex.html
```

Can this be accomplished?

Comment: Not out of the box. genindex.html is a special page generated by Sphinx. You would need to dive into its inner workings and write some Python code to make it happen. See https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/_modules/sphinx/builders/html.html and https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#special-names

Comment: @StevePiercy Thanks; guess I'll just set the page to one of them instead of including both.

Comment: Can't do this either it seems (toctree)

Comment: Correct, because they are not source files. Sphinx creates special pages automagically. You could however use `:ref:'genindex'` replacing `'` with backticks.